# Camera can not open when visit the webXR sample web page

Tags: google-chrome, augmented-reality, webxr

I am new to web XR device API, I want to do some webAR test, there are two questions, any help would be appreciate.
1. Is webXR need ARCore, ARKit or other third part SDK to run AR?
2. The phone camera can not open when I visit this link https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/hit-test.html used google chrome 81,

I used two phones to test this link: SAMGSUN S7 edge and HUAWEI P20 Pro, nothing happened except the grey background.so what I have missed, why?